# QooxDoo - Firefox renders Indigo Theme Gradient in 270 degree

Tags: qooxdoo

have any one faced this problem in firefox with Qooxdoo..

***Firefox renders Qooxdoo UI element's gradient in 270 degree angle.***
[image: Firefox renders:]

***Same qooxdoo page in Google Chrome:***
[image: Google Chrome Renders:]

**Is there is any way to fix it??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens only in combination with Firefox and `qooxdoo <= 2.0.1`. Maybe you want to upgrade. This is covered by the [migration documentation](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/tool/migration/migration_guide.html).

See gradient behaviour:

- http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.0.1/playground/   (not ok)
- http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.0.2/playground/   (ok)
- http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.0.3/playground/   (ok)
- http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.0.4/playground/   (ok)
- http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.1/playground/     (ok)
- http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.1.1/playground/   (ok)

Comment: Oh.. Thanks. Richard Sternagel